# Write a markdown parser in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, parsing, markdown

I am considering writing a markdown parser in Objective C.

Can anyone explain the basic algorithm of doing this?
Is there any library I can look at? I'm not familiar with C. Python or Obj-C implementation would be nice.

The parser should not focus on HTML or any other output. Instead it focuses on detecting the markdown syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Languages are specified by their *grammar*, you need to look at a Markdown grammar to implement a parser.

Comment: I have Objective-C experience. I am working on a project that potentially needs to parse markdown, but no need to output html.

Comment: So are you *considering writing a markdown parser*, or are you asking us to write a markdown parser for you?

Answer (score 0):

Markdown is essentially specified by the [original Perl script that parses it](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

It doesn't fit neatly into a standard parser architecture unfortunately (there isn't a formal grammar as such), it is based on a multi-pass set of string manipulations and regular expression pattern matching/replacement.  If you read through the Perl script you will see what I mean.

The best way to achieve your goal is to hand transcode the Perl script into Obj-C, as has been done for other languages.

Comment: Do you know any implementation of this in Objective-C or Python?

Comment: Discount is written in C, and so therefore is (almost) also written in Objective-C.

Comment: The [current version of MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) is also written in C and very fast.